# query for sql to retrive id deistic value count

Tags: sql, select

I want to resolve below issue but not able to figure out how I can do that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `distinct` keyword to get the number of different values in a `count` expression:

```
SELECT   sensor_id, COUNT(DISTINCT event_type) types
FROM     events
GROUP BY sensor_id
ORDER BY sensor_id ASC
```